# Setting deterministic distributions in PyMC3

Tags: python, pymc3

I'm new to PyMC3 
Here is some PyMC2 - do I need to do something specific like compile in Theano to convert this to PyMC3 code?

```
 @pymc.deterministic
    def away_theta(home_team=home_team, 
                   away_team=away_team, 
                   home=home, 
                   atts=atts, 
                   defs=defs, 
                   intercept=intercept): 
        return np.exp(intercept + 
                      atts[away_team] + 
                      defs[home_team])
```

I get an error like

```
AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert home_theta to TensorType', <class 'pymc.PyMCObjects.Deterministic'>)
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I will have a play

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, determinstic transformations need to be theano expressions in pymc3. So instead of using np.exp you'd use theano.tensor.exp:

```
import theano.tensor as T
import pymc3 as pm

with Model():
    ...
    regression = pm.Deterministic('regression', T.exp(intercept + atts[away_team] + defs[home_team]))
    ...
```